# Error in calling APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_MAX_IDLE_SECONDS

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ebs

I am calling an APEX page from EBS. I have written a code in Before header to set the session values.

```
lv_profile_value := NVL(xxua_apex_common_pkg.fnd_profile_value 
                        ('ICX_SESSION_TIMEOUT'),'0');
:EBS_ICX_SESSION_TIMEOUT := TO_NUMBER(lv_profile_value)*10;
 APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_MAX_IDLE_SECONDS (p_seconds => 
                                             :EBS_ICX_SESSION_TIMEOUT);
```

Here the fnd_profile_value for 'ICX_SESION_TIMEOUT' is set to 240.

Now if I use :

```
:EBS_ICX_SESSION_TIMEOUT := TO_NUMBER(lv_profile_value)*10;
```

Then I get this error : 'ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large'

But If I just write

```
 :EBS_ICX_SESSION_TIMEOUT := TO_NUMBER(lv_profile_value)*9;
```

Everything works fine. Can somebody please suggest why it gives no error when I multiply by 9(240*9=2160) and gives an error when multiplied by 10 (240*10=2400).

The value gets properly set in my varaible :'EBS_ICX_SESSION_TIMEOUT'

But when APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_MAX_IDLE_SECONDS is called it throws this error.

Please suggest.

Comment: What happens if you try `:EBS_ICX_SESSION_TIMEOUT := round(TO_NUMBER(lv_profile_value))*10;`, i.e. ROUND the result first, then multiply it?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion...but it doesn't help..I get the same error after using ROUND also..